# Result of calculation is always 0

Tags: c++, calculation, cmath

I'm simulating a loan payment calculator and I'm sure I used the right equation and data types. Am I missing a data type conversion or something? Am I doing something that isn't allowed in C++?

I've tried reordering variables in the equation, changing data types of variables and functions, moving the equation outside of functions.

```
float annualInterestRate,
       payment,
       periodRate = annualInterestRate / 1200.0;

int loanAmount,
    years,
    months = years * 12;

int mortgageLoanMinimum = 100000,
    carLoanMinimum = 5000,
    carLoanMaximum = 200000;

float mortgageRateMinimum = 2.0,
       mortgageRateMaximum = 12.0,
       carRateMinimum = 0.0,
       carRateMaximum = 15.0;

int mortgageTermMinimum = 15,
    mortgageTermMaximum = 30,
    carTermMinimum = 3,
    carTermMaximum = 6;
```

```cpp
float mortgage() {

    cout << "How much money do you want to borrow? (Nothing less than $100,000): ";
    cin >> loanAmount;
    cout << "How much annual interest rate by percent? (2.0% - 12.0%): ";
    cin >> annualInterestRate;
    cout << "For how many years? (15 - 30 Years): ";
    cin >> years;

    payment = (loanAmount * periodRate * pow((1 + periodRate), months)) / (pow((1 + periodRate), months));



    return(payment);

}
```

When choosing a mortgage, entering 500000 for loanAmount, 4.5 for annualInterestRate, and 30 for years, I expected payment to be 2533.80 but it's always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared periodRate as

`periodRate = annualInterestRate / 1200.0;`

However, when periodRate is declared, annulaInterestRate is compiler-initialized value, which is 0.0f, that means periodRate = 0.0f, too. Here, you need to use define

`#define periodRate (annualInterestRate / 1200.0)`

Same for months, too.

`#define months (years * 12)`

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are initialised to 0 in C++.

When you do

```
int loanAmount,
years,
months = years * 12;
```

`years` is initialized to 0, and `months` is initialized to therefore 0 * 12 = 0. Since you never update the value of `months` to not be 0, the calculation will always 0.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
float annualInterestRate,
       payment,
       periodRate = annualInterestRate / 1200.0;

int loanAmount,
    years,
    months = years * 12;
```

don't do what I think you want them to do.

`periodicRate` and `months` get initialized to 0. However, they don't get updated when you read the values of `annualInterestRate` and `years` from user input.

You need to compute `periodicRate` and `months` after `annualInterestRate` and `years` have been read .

```
float mortgage() {

    cout << "How much money do you want to borrow? (Nothing less than $100,000): ";
    cin >> loanAmount;
    cout << "How much annual interest rate by percent? (2.0% - 12.0%): ";
    cin >> annualInterestRate;
    cout << "For how many years? (15 - 30 Years): ";
    cin >> years;

    float periodRate = annualInterestRate / 1200.0;
    int months = years * 12;

    payment = (loanAmount * periodRate * pow((1 + periodRate), months)) / (pow((1 + periodRate), months));

    return(payment);
}
```

With that change in place, you can remove the global variables `periodicRate` and `months`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the method I chose for the sake of pretty organization IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you’re mistaking how

```
months = years * 12;
```

Is actually working.

When that statement is executed, it sets the value of `months` to 12 times the current value of `years`. It does not tell the computer that months should *always* be 12 times the value of `years`. Right now, when the statement runs, the value of `years` is not yet set, and so `years * 12 == 0`.

You can fix your code by assigning a value to `months` after getting the user input for `years` or by replacing `months` in your calculation with `12 * years`.